# xargs: how to have literal double-quotes in replacement?

Tags: json, bash, curl, xargs

I have a source file with JSON-Objects one per line like this:

source:

```
{"_id":"1","name":"one"}
{"_id":"2","name":"two"}
{"_id":"3","name":"three"}
```

I want to send each line to a

```
curl -X POST -H "application/json" myURL -d '<REPLACEMENT>'
```

The double quotes do not make it to curl when I am trying

```
<source xargs -I % curl -X POST -H "application/json" myURL -d '%'
```

I tried escaping the quotes in the curl command and later I replaced all double-quotes in the source file with \". I found no version to work.

Another approach to use seq with sed to write each line into a temp file and curl -d @temp did not work out for me.

Is there an elegant solution or do I have to write a script with a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU Parallel was built specifically to deal with `xargs` bad handling of special chars:

```
<source parallel curl -X POST -H "application/json" myURL -d {}
```

Not only will it quote " correctly, it will quote *any* string correctly, so it will be interpreted as a single argument by curl.

Added bonus: Your queries will run in parallel - one query per cpu.

Comment: Thx, sounds good! I was lucky: parallel is a known recipe of homebrew - so it is installed - try it later. Thx so far for the hint!

Comment: Ok, "parallel" instead of xargs did help with this change: the H-value quoting had to be escaped too: `<t.json parallel  -t curl -X POST -H \'Content-Type: application/json\'  http://xxxx.iriscouch.com/xxxx -d {}` ... curl then gets called with a d-value of an unquoted JSON string with all inner double-quotes and blanks escaped. Probably would fail when the json field values contain quotes ;)

Answer (score 9):

That's an interesting problem. There must be a better solution (perhaps konsolebox is onto something), but substituting all `"` with `\"` would work:

```
$ echo '"hello"'
"hello"
$ echo '"hello"' | xargs echo
hello
$ echo '"hello"' | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | xargs echo
"hello"
```

Comment: In fact I need two levels of quotations to be send to the looped curl: the inner " are part of the json syntax and the outer ' limit the value of the -d prameter. I tried with escaping the source but with curl -d '%' I had no luck. Maybe try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Should do the trick:

```
cat source.json | xargs -0 -I {} curl {}
```

From `man xargs`:

> ```
>   -0, --null
>          Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special (ev‐
>          ery  character  is  taken  literally).  Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful
>          when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.  The GNU find -print0 option produces input suit‐
>          able for this mode.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--data-urlencode`:

```
<source xargs -I % curl -X POST -H "application/json" myURL --data-urlencode '%'
```

The option may be used with other formats. See the manual of `curl`. You can also try `--data-binary`.

Comment: Thanks. Does not help. I need to escape the single quotes around % to \'%\' - but neither in urlendcode nor binary mode the inner double quotes come through. The behaviour of curl when receiving the broken json is even worse.